# Prop value lost after running a method Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I made a material design input field as a Vue component. I listen for the focus event and run a function to check the value every time the user focuses out. Here's the code:

```
<template>
<span class="h-input-container">
    <input :type="type" :name="name" v-validate="validation" 
@focusout="classHandle" :id="id" :value="value">
    <p :class="focusClass"><i :class="icon"></i>&nbsp;{{placeholder}}</p>
</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted: function(){
        if (this.value != '') {
            this.focusClass = 'focused'
        }
    },
    props: {
        placeholder: {
            default: ''
        },
        name: {
            default: 'no-name'
        },
        type: {
            default: 'text'
        },
        validation: {
            default: ''
        },
        icon: {
            default: ''
        },
        id: {
            default: ''
        },
        value: {
            default: ''
        }
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            focusClass: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        classHandle: function(event){
            if (event.target.value != '') {
                this.focusClass = 'focused'
            } else {
                this.focusClass = ''
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I pass the value as a prop called `value` and I've used that value for the input field using `:value="value"`. The thing is, every time the method `classHandle` runs, the input field's value disappears. I can't figure out why.

Comment: 'validation' doesn't look like a typical 'v-validate' rule. What does it do?

Comment: @BertEvans it's not a v-validate rule, it's a prop that I pass in a custom value to. That value, of course should be an existing rule.

Comment: Is it your expectation that whatever you are passing in as value is changing outside the component as well when you edit it with this component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify the accepted answer, Vue does not "refresh" the value when the `focusout` handler fires. The property, `value`, never changed, the input element's value changed.

Changing the `focusClass` forces Vue to re-render the component to the DOM. Because you've told Vue to use the property, `value`, as the value of the input via `:value="value"`, it uses the current state of the property, **which has never changed** as stated above, to render the component and whatever you typed in the input disappears.

The accepted answer goes on to state that you should fix this by updating `this.value`. In a component, Vue will allow you to do that but it will throw a warning in the console.

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
> overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
> data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
> mutated: "value"

Properties of components in Vue are just like function arguments in javascript. Inside the component, you *can* change them, but that change is limited to the scope of the component. If the *parent* component ever has to re-render, then the property "value" of your input will be redrawn using the parent's version of the value, and you will lose your changes.

[Component communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) in Vue "props down, events up". In order to change the value outside your component, you have to `$emit` it. Here is a version of your component that works, without throwing any warnings, and properly emits your changes.

```
{
  props: {
    placeholder: {
      default: ''
    },
    name: {
      default: 'no-name'
    },
    type: {
      default: 'text'
    },
    validation: {
      default: ''
    },
    icon: {
      default: ''
    },
    id: {
      default: ''
    },
    value: {
      default: ''
    }
  },
  template:`
    <div class="h-input-container" style="background-color: lightgray">
        <input :type="type" :name="name"  
    @focusout="classHandle" :id="id" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
        <p :class="focusClass"><i :class="icon"></i>&nbsp;{{placeholder}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      focusClass: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    classHandle: function(event) {
      if (event.target.value != '') {
        this.focusClass = 'focused'
      } else {
        this.focusClass = ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've put together an [example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VpoLvZ?editors=1010) to demonstrate the differences in the two approaches.

Typically, I would not use `:value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"` and use `v-model` instead, but you are using `:type="type"` as well, and Vue will throw a warning about using `v-model` with a dynamic type.

Comment: I replaced @input="updateValue" to @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" but it doesn't seem to work. I'm obviously missing something. what is it?

Comment: Most likely you are binding to your component using :value when you should use v-model.

Answer (score 0):

Your current component do not seems to refresh `this.value` when you make change in the input. Vue cause a component refresh when you focusOut, and because your value is not updated, it shown empy. To resolve your problem, you need to update `this.value` on event `input`

```js
new Vue(
{
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    placeholder: {
      default: ''
    },
    name: {
      default: 'no-name'
    },
    type: {
      default: 'text'
    },
    validation: {
      default: ''
    },
    icon: {
      default: ''
    },
    id: {
      default: ''
    },
    value: {
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      focusClass: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(event) {
     this.value = event.target.value
    },
    classHandle: function(event) {
      if (event.target.value != '') {
        this.focusClass = 'focused'
      } else {
        this.focusClass = ''
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<span class="h-input-container">
    <input :type="type" :name="name" v-validate="validation" 
@focusout="classHandle" :id="id" :value="value" @input="updateValue" />
    <p :class="focusClass"><i :class="icon"></i>&nbsp;{{placeholder}}</p>
</span>
</div>
```

So you should put your attention on:

```
@input="updateValue"
```

And

```
updateValue(event) {
    this.value = event.target.value
}
```

Comment: Cheers, it works. I'm curious though, why does Vue refresh the value when I focusout? Does it serve a purpose?